# inserting a blank row within foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a php loop as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($dcr_all as $key=>$d):?>

  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>     

        <td >
          <?php $date_in = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];
                 $date_in = new DateTime($date_in);
                 echo $date_in = $date_in -> format('h:i a');
           ?>
        </td>
  </tr>        

<?php  endforeach;?>
```

My question is that how to insert a blank row between current row and the previous row if the time difference `($date_in)` between the two rows is greater than 1 hour..

here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 02:00:00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 02:11:00
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 02:23:00
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 04:00:00
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 04:12:00
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 06:00:00
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [DailyCallReport] => Array
                (
                    [datetime_in] => 2016-02-25 06:09:00
                )

        )

)
```

[image]

Here is the image of my table.. In the row no 3 and 4 there is a time difference between them is more than 1 hour so i just want a display a blank row with a message with no index number..

Comment: How is your array `$dcr_all` built? Can you post a `var_dump` of it?

Comment: can you share a screen shot after replacing your code with mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$dcr_all = Array
(
    0 => array (
    'DailyCallReport' => Array
            (
                'datetime_in' => '2016-02-25 02:00:00'
            )

    ),


1 => Array
    (
        'DailyCallReport' => Array
            (
                'datetime_in' => '2016-02-25 02:11:00'
            )

    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'DailyCallReport' => Array
            (
                'datetime_in' => '2016-02-25 02:23:00'
            )

    ),

3 => Array
    (
        'DailyCallReport' => Array
            (
                'datetime_in' => '2016-02-25 04:00:00'
            )

    )
 ); 


 $date_in = '';
 foreach ($dcr_all as $key=>$d):
    if($date_in != $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in']){
      if($date_in == ''){
         $date_in = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];

      }
      else{
          $current_row_date = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];

          if(strtotime($current_row_date) - (strtotime($date_in)+3600) >= 3600){
             $date_in = $current_row_date;
             echo '<br/>';
          }
      }?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>     

        <td >
         <?php 
         $date_in = new DateTime($date_in);
         echo $date_in = $date_in -> format('h:i a');
       ?>
       </td>
      </tr> 
  <?php
  }
  endforeach;
?>
```

This is the fiddle [link](http://phpfiddle.org/lite)

Comment: Which part has problem? does blank row generated or no? or in date comparison?

Comment: sorry there is no any black row its show error on date format

Comment: The data array that I used only match in 3 element of array not in two other because the time difference is less than 1 hr

Answer (score 0):

You just keep track of the last date time. So don't overwrite it with the format when you echo it out. Then do a date diff on each iteration.

```
<?php $date_in = null; ?>
<?php foreach ($dcr_all as $key=>$d):?>

<?php
if ($date_in && $date_in->diff(new DateTime($d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in']))->format('%h') >= 1) {
    echo "<tr><td></td><td>Message here</td></tr>";
}
?>

  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>     

        <td >
          <?php $date_in = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];
                 $date_in = new DateTime($date_in);
                 //don't overwrite the $date_in with the format here
                 echo $date_in->format('h:i a');
           ?>
        </td>
  </tr>        

<?php  endforeach;?>
```

Comment: yes it works but without data-table pagination.. if i enable data-table pagination option the rows are generated at the top of the table

Comment: You're wasting everybody's time here.... You didn't specify that in the question. I'd appreciate an up vote at least...

Comment: how could i know that it do not working with data table pagination. your code is working but without datatble pagination

Comment: Your issue is somewhere else then.... My post answers the question you asked. So there's obviously something else causing problems - most likely javascript related.

Comment: my pleasure, maybe mark this answer as correct, just in case someone else has a similar issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for you question. just replace your script with current one and you will get a blank row there.

```
<?php 
$lastRowDateTime = null;
foreach ($dcr_all as $key=>$d):
    $date_in = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];
    if (!is_null($lastRowDateTime) && strtotime($date_in) > strtotime($lastRowDateTime)+3600) {
        ?>
        <tr><td>your message goes here</td></tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>     

        <td>
            <?php
            $date_in = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];
            $date_in = new DateTime($date_in);
            echo $date_in = $date_in -> format('h:i a');
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

   <?php
    $lastRowDateTime = $d['DailyCallReport']['datetime_in'];
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: all blank rows are generated in the beginning of the table.. i want to display in between the two row

Comment: @iSemanticsTechnology try now it will insert a extra row with message each time time difference increases one hour

Comment: but the rows are generated at the end of the table not in between the two rows

Comment: @iSemanticsTechnology see this code working here it inserts a new a between two rows https://3v4l.org/Vj6g0

Comment: yes it works but without data-table pagination.. if i enable data-table pagination option the rows are generated on the bottom of the table

Comment: @iSemanticsTechnology could you accept this as it is fine according to your question but jquery.datatable is something else.

Comment: is it possible to do it with datatable pagination

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104508/discussion-between-mubeen1992-and-isemantics-technology).